# Failed to call web3.utils.sha3 on truffle console

Tags: truffle

I try to call

```
web3.utils.sha3('234');
```

on truffle console. However I got an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sha3' of undefined
at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:11
at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:35:29)
at Object.runInContext (vm.js:89:6)
at Console.interpret (C:\Users\aa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:202201:17)
at ReplManager.interpret (C:\Users\aa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:202917:18)
at bound (domain.js:280:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:538:10)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

Does this mean web3.utils.sha3 has not supported yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you're trying to use the [web3.js 1.0 syntax](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html?highlight=sha3) of `web3.utils.sha3(string)` but the latest version of truffle actually uses [web3 0.20.1](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3sha3) which has the syntax `web3.sha3(string [, options])`. Try that instead.